# iphone: upload image to server using ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I have to upload an image to server for which I  wrote code using NSMutableURLRequest like this

```
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
//  
//  /*
//   now lets create the body of the post
//   */
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile%@.jpg\"\r\n",self.fileID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I guess my PHP script respond corresponding to this and is working fine

how can I replicate above in ASIFormDataRequest?

tried to do this

```
ASIFormDataRequest* request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL: 
                               [NSURL URLWithString:photoUploadURLString]]; 


NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile%@.jpg\"\r\n",self.fileID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request addData:body withFileName:filename andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"snapshot[image]"]; 
request.uploadProgressDelegate = self.progressView; 
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(getFacebookPhotoFinished:)];
```

but didnt got sucess?

here are the details of my PHP scripts

```
<?php 

$uploaddir = './uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http://example.com/uploads/{$file}";
}

?>
```

I did as per Cyprian

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"images/ipodfile%@.jpg", fileID]];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([itemImageView image], 0.05);
if (imageData != nil) {
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
}
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:savedImagePath contents:imageData attributes:nil])
{
    NSLog(@"Image saved");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Image not saved");
}           


[activityIndicator startAnimating];
NSString *photoUploadURLString = @"http://example.com/imageuploader.php";

NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ipodfile%@.jpg", self.fileID];
NSLog(@"url  is %@/%@",photoUploadURLString, filename);

UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
newImage=[itemImageView image];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:photoUploadURLString];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"userfile" forKey:@"name"];
[request setPostValue:filename forKey:@"filename"];

[request setData:imageData withFileName:filename andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"snapshot[image]"];
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what goes wrong?

Comment: my question is simple how van I post image using ASIHTTP request so that above mentioned PHP script can save image to uploads directory

Comment: No error? No response from server? Hard to tell what's wrong here. Provide some more details, I don't that we can guess what's going wrong in your code.

Comment: please dont misunderstand but I am not at all sure of how to replicate that mutable request to asi request

Comment: Please follow [this][1]
Nicely answerd

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115587/asiformdatarequest-post-request-issue

Answer (score 13):

Uploading file to server using ASIFormDataRequest

```
-(void)uploadFile{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: photoUploadURLString];

        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
        //if you have your site secured by .htaccess

        //[request setUsername:@"login"];
        //[request setPassword:@"password"];


        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ipodfile%@.jpg",self.fileID];
        [request addPostValue:fileName forKey:@"name"];

        // Upload an image
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageName:fileName])
        [request setData:imageData withFileName:fileName andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"userfile"];

        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
        [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];

        [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)uploadRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{    
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
        NSLog("Upload response %@", responseString);
}

- (void)uploadRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

        NSLog(@" Error - Statistics file upload failed: \"%@\"",[[request error] localizedDescription]); 
}
```

**Note** I was typing from memory so you may have some misspellings.

Comment: it will work if you clarify the following: What parameters do you want to send? Tell me the content and the key pairs like this: `file name for key "name"` ... and so on

Comment: The question is this: what parameters do you expect on the server side? I don't know PHP but if you expect to get data for file in the parameter userfile and the image name in the parameter name then my updated code should work for you.

Comment: How can upload more than one image to server using same parameter?

Comment: what is file ID it is working but im not getting any response its like - Upload Response - in nslog no string at all

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *strURL = @"enter uerl hear...";

//      ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]]; // Upload a file on disk 
NSString *filename1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"friendship.jpg"]; 
UIImage *image1=[UIImage imageNamed:filename1];
NSData *imageData1=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 1.0); 
[request setData:imageData1 withFileName:filename1 andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"avatar"]; 
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
//[request appendPostData:body]; 
[request setDelegate:self]; 
[request setTimeOutSeconds:3.0]; 
request.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection = NO;
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)]; 
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)]; 
[request startAsynchronous];


- (void)uploadRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
 NSLog(@" Error - Statistics file upload failed: \"%@\"",[request responseString]); 
}

- (void)uploadRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{ 
NSLog(@" Error - Statistics file upload failed: \"%@\"",[[request error] localizedDescription]); 

}
```

Comment: your code works great, how do I pass text param with the file one, when I try I got exception +1

Comment: How to upload multiple images to server using same parameter?