# ASIFormDataRequest POST Request Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, post, asiformdatarequest

im using this code to post data to my server

```
NSURL *mainurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxxxxx/api/PhonePaymentApi/Transaction/"];

    NSString * postdata = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"UniqueId=%@&jsonProduct=%@&BranchId=%@&OrderToTime=%@",GETUnicidentifire,JsonOrderDetail,BranchId,OrderToTime];

    ASIFormDataRequest *requestt = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:mainurl];

    [requestt setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [requestt addRequestHeader:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" value:@"Content-Type"];
    [requestt appendPostData:[postdata dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString * theurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mainurl];
    NSURLRequest *thereqest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theurl]];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:thereqest delegate:self];
```

in the method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"%@",error); 
}
```

im geting:
{Message:The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.}

what im doing Wrong ?

Comment: If this is new code don't use ASI, it is no longer being developed. [ASIHTTP page](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) The current replacement is [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) which is currently being developed/supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing things up here. You build an `ASIFormDataRequest`, but you don't actually send it. What you do send is an `NSURLConnection`.

It's been a long time since I've used ASI, but this might help:

```
NSURL *mainurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxxxxx/api/PhonePaymentApi/Transaction/"];

ASIFormDataRequest *requestt = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:mainurl];

[requestt addPostValue:GETUnicidentifire forKey:@"UniqueId";
[requestt addPostValue:JsonOrderDetail   forKey:@"jsonProduct";
[requestt addPostValue:BranchId          forKey:@"BranchId";
[requestt addPostValue:OrderToTime       forKey:@"OrderToTime";

[requestt setCompletionBlock:^{
    // Process the response
}];
[requestt setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [requestt error];
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];

[requestt startAsynchronous];
```

---

As a word of advice, replace ASI with something like AFNetworking. ASI is no longer being developed.